# Unable to launch program made with Visual Studio on a computer without VS installed

Tags: visual-studio, release

I am  trying to launch an .exe of a c++ app made in VS without VS installed but without success.
Here is what I did:
I compiled the program in release mode,
Manually moved all the files from debug to release folder, as well as game library files. Then pasted the vcruntime140d.dll file there because it prompted me to do so. NOW when I double click on the exe file it says the following: Application wasnt properly launched 0xc000007b. Installing VS redistributable package did not help. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: You copied the wrong file.  First make sure you build the Release version of your program so you do not need the debug build of the vcruntime.  Then focus on the Platform you selected, the 32-bit flavor of the DLL is located in c:\windows\syswow64.  Not a typo.

Comment: I ended up manually copying the source code and resources to Dev C++ and there it works flawlessly :D

Answer (score 0):

**How to export an Allegro 5 game**

I finally figured out what to do:

- go to build > configuration manager, change for release and x86 platform.
- add all necessary addons in properties > allegro 5 > addons
- copy all the game files (images, music, etc.) as well as allegro 5 .dll files to your release folder

**Boom**. it is now launchable.